# MismatchSenderId even when it's correct

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm following this tutorial https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/#send_a_request_from_the_command_line_for_fcm_to_push_a_message

I did everything as is instructed there so far. However when I do a curl request I get back

```
{"multicast_id":6771552758811002436,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}
```

I checked it billion times I have put correct senderId in my manifest.json in `"gcm_sender_id"`

So why would I get such error?

Here are some more details.
In the tutorial it says to get the keys from FCM console in cloud messaging

[image: I get the keys from here]

This is how my manifest.json looks like

```
{
  "name":"Push Notifications codelab",
  "gcm_sender_id":"773185791049"
}
```

And this is how I send the request

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=AIzaSyCQHb2t8c3N255bH_CVmGych5QcNntFxYg" --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"APA91bE4RJ7_9m2eJ_zlg1F90bLjVX8ctVpCBN24ElAXF--4wS_nnxg4LzkbJWeTe-peMN_StmOaQTEoGeCCNZE5Mssux3T-KbfGRVmRWzeQZM8opfUyv7FVjI9iEfETHG3O7i1qkIb-\"]}"
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct registration token?

Comment: I'll add some more details to the question now.

Comment: I was referring to the registration token. If you're not using the one you generated using your Sender ID, then you'll always receive MismatchSenderId. Also, please **NEVER** expose your Server Key to the public, same with your Sender ID. These details should be kept secret.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by registration token, there's nothing about it in the tutorial. Can you please tell me more?

Comment: The Subscription ID in the link you're following. Sorry. It's more commonly known as registration token, that's why I keep on saying it.

Comment: oh okay so you mean the subscription id from the endpoint value, right?
`https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send/cl72SS1zE50:APA91bE4RJ7_9m2eJ_zlg1F90bLjVX8ctVpCBN24ElAXF--4wS_nnxg4LzkbJWeTe-peMN_StmOaQTEoGeCCNZE5Mssux3T-KbfGRVmRWzeQZM8opfUyv7FVjI9iEfETHG3O7i1qkIb-`

subscription id is the part starting with APA91 till the end, isn't it?

Comment: Yup. That's it. You can get the MismatchSenderId error if you're using the wrong SenderID or a registration token that is subsribed to a different SederID. I'm seeing some spaces on your registration token. Or is it just with the comment format?

Comment: Well there are no spaces when I send it via terminal, and I checked it all again. Everything seems to be correct. The only suspicious thing I am able to find is that the example registration id format seems to be a bit different than the one I get. This is the example 
`APA91bHMaA-R0eZrPisZCGfwwd7z1EzL7P7Q7cyocVkxBU3nXWed1cQYCYvFglMHIJ40kn-jZENQ62UFgg5QnEcqwB5dFZ-AmNZjATO8QObGp0p1S6Rq2tcCuUibjnyaS0UF1gIM1mPeM25MdZdNVLG3dM6ZSfxV8itpihroEN5ANj9A26RU2Uw`

Comment: The registration id has no specific format, so I think it's fine. Have you tried sending a message via the Firebase Console? See if it'll go through?

Comment: I am not informed how to do that, can you please tell me?